# Push data to flex client

Tags: apache-flex, flash, push, push-notification, server-push

Howday,

I want to push data to flex clients.
I am talking about anywhere between 5000-15000 concurrent users, need to get data every time a currency is changed so that means lots of changes for lots of users.

I have been looking into WebOrb.net, but the performance seem very poor (100 users concurrent) for a product so pricy (we purchased a license).

So, I have to look into alternatives, I know there's fluorineFx but it seems no one is really using it for products and it lacks in examples and documentation.

My question is:
what products can answer my needs (.net backend) and what are the performance I can expect out of these products?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what part of weborb would have poor performance.  We use it here with a few thousand concurrent users, each of whom has multiple application windows and each window is subscribed to five message queues (rtmp/msmq messages -- receiving HUGE value objects that can hold screen-shots, etc.).  This does not include the remote Operations that each screen/app window is running.  How are you testing?  What does your .NET side look like?  How do multiple db queries work w/ a single request?  Is your global.asax bogging things down or should it be optimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, the strength of both WebOrb and FluorineFx is primarily in remoting (remote procedure calls, remote objects) and not necessarily in pushing data updates as efficiently as possible, for the kind of application you describe.

Perhaps you could instead look into using low-level socket communication, which can be more specialized in pushing updates efficiently.

I don't know of any products off-hand, but I guess stuff used for chats or multiplayer games could be somewhat relevant. Otherwise, it is probably fairly doable to roll your own socket communication in ActionScript/.Net.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html